# Search on a Numeric Field in a keyword query with Hibernate Search 5

Tags: hibernate-search

I've tried many ways to search, in a keyword query, for a Long field in my database. I always got errors because Hibernate Search will index the Long as a numeric field. I've tried using FieldBridge, but it just wouldn't work. Here is my field I want to search on.

```java
@Field
@Column(unique = true)
private Long numericField;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything online on this issue so I'm posting my answer here Q&A-style. I figured a way to do it with a dynamic field, see below:

```java
@Column(unique = true)
private Long numericField;

@Field(name="numericField", analyze = Analyze.NO, index=Index.YES)
public String getNumericFieldAsString(){
    return numericField.toString();
}
```

The field is indexed dynamically as a String now and I can use it in my keyword query.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword queries support long fields just fine: you just have to provide a long value when querying, because the field is of type long. So just use `Long.parseLong` to turn the text value provided by your user into a long before you pass it to Hibernate Search.

In some cases, you may really need to use a string field for your numeric value. For example if you're targeting multiple fields in the same keyword query, and some of the other fields are string fields.

Then [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64802101/6692043) will work fine, though it unfortunately has some side effects that will cause Hibernate Search to reindex data more often (because it doesn't know where `getNumbericFieldAsString` gets its data from exactly).

Alternatively, you could use bridges, either a custom one, or just this one which is built into Hibernate Search 5:

```java
@Column(unique = true)
@Field(name="numericField", analyze = Analyze.NO, bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.LongBridge.class))
private Long numericField;
```

For information about custom bridges, [see here for Hibernate Search 5](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-bridges) and [here for Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge) (the newer version of Hibernate Search, with a different API).